# Beginner Blazor issue: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback'

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I am creating my first Blazor app and I have two components named child and parent:

child:

```
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
    @Title
</div>

<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
    @ChildContent
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="onClickMethod">Primary</button>


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback onClickMethod { get; set; }
}
```

Parent:

```
@page "/childcomp"

<h3>ParentComponent</h3>
<BlazingShop.Pages.Components.ChildComponent OnClickMethod="@ShowMessage"
                                             Title="This title is from parent"> This is between component of the parent</BlazingShop.Pages.Components.ChildComponent>

<p><b>@messageText</b></p>

@code {
    private string messageText;
    private void ShowMessage()
    {
        messageText = "Blazing Text from Parent";
    }

}
```

In the Parent section, the `@ShowMessage"` is red and I see the error. I am following an online tutorial, and this is happening only on my side. What how I fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a casing issue on your parent.

In your child component, the `EventCallback` property has a name of `onClickMethod`. On the parent you are using `OnClickMethod`. These properties are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Use standard C# conventions to name your parameters en Components.

```
   [Parameter]
// public EventCallback onClickMethod { get; set; }
   public EventCallback OnClickMethod { get; set; }
```